# excel - drop down list with condition

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

Maybe the title of the question is wrong, but I'll try to explain what I'm looking for. I have in cell A1 a `drop down list` to select months (from 1-12). Is it possible to automatically fill the rest of the A column with hourly data for the whole selected month. For example if it's selected "3" in A column'd be:

```
Time                
1.3.2018 1:00:00    
1.3.2018 2:00:00    
1.3.2018 3:00:00
...
31.3.2018 22:00:00
31.3.2018 23:00:00
1.4.2018 0:00:00
```

Maybe, something like second `drop down list`.

Or maybe, it can be done with `substitute`, but then some months have 31 days, some 30, and february 28, and there is a problem with daylight saving time. In 3rd month, there's one day where I need to have 23 hours (jump from 02:00 to 04:00), and in 10th month one day with 25 hours (02:00, 02:00, 03:00).

Comment: why are you not thinking of `DATE` function?

Answer (score 1):

In cell A2 enter the following formula:

```
=DATE(2018,A1,1)
```

Then custom format the cell with type:

```
d.m.yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

In Cell A3 enter the following formula:

```
=A2+1/24
```

And change the cell format as above, then drag the cell down to autofill until you have the full month.

Comment: Thanks: I've done something similar with additional column and substitute, but there's a problem with 3rd and 10th month (daylight saving time). In 3rd month, there's one day where I need to have 23 hours (jump from 02:00 to 04:00), and in 10th month one day with 25 hours (02:00, 02:00, 03:00).

Comment: Oh.. I saw the answer posted after I refreshed. none of these address DST issue though. @CreakushColiko  You should add this requirement in your question itself

Answer (score 1):

There would be multiple ways, but one way is to first determine number of rows required (for March it would be 31 * 24 = 744), set first row using `DATE` function and then keep adding 1 hour until the desired row number is reached.

Calculate number of rows required in `A2`: `=DAY(EOMONTH(A3,0))*24+ROW()`

in `A3` enter `=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),A1,1)`

in `A4` enter `=IF(ROW()<=$A$2,A3+1/24,"")` and drag down till about 800.

This will make it dynamic for number of days in month